# Trouble to deploy an app in azure web app React

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm triying to deploy a frontend app with Reac, the repository is hosted in github so I'm using github actions to continuous implementation.

The github actions says that the build and deploy are working correctly but when I tried to use the url http://<>.azurewebsites.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud9Gr.png)

it return 503 error "The service is unavailable"

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the (enterprise) application registry for this app to reflect what it does. Else the App Service cannot serve your application.

Look for the Platform Configuration in authentication blade.